# How to delete one line before a specific word in a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-handling

so I have text file `file.txt` e.g

```
something1
something2
something3
line to be removed
2022-07-21 >>  Ctrl+S
something4
something5
something6
something7
line to be removed
2022-07-21 >>  Ctrl+S
```

now how do I make it delete **one** line **before** the word `Ctrl+S` in the whole file.

So that the outputfile will be

```
something1
something2
something3
2022-07-21 >>  Ctrl+S
something4
something5
something6
something7
2022-07-21 >>  Ctrl+S
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

```
keyword = 'Ctrl+S'
new_content = []

with open('textfile.txt', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    prev_index = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(content):
        if keyword in line:
            new_content += content[prev_index:i - 1]
            prev_index = i
    new_content += content[prev_index:]
with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("".join(new_content))
```

Thanks and Credits to mister @AndersHaarbergEriksen

`link` https://stackoverflow.com/a/73070745/19284077

**OR With a Single open**

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for pos, line in enumerate(lines):
        if len(lines)-1 !=pos:
            if "Ctrl+S" in lines[pos+1]:
                continue
        f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```

Credits : @Ameen Ali Shaikh

`link` https://stackoverflow.com/a/73070970/19284077

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```py
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

text = re.sub(r'(Ctrl\+S)(\n[^\n]+)(?=\nCtrl\+S)', '\\1\\3', text)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: This answer requires that the file fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("file.txt",'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

excludedWord = "whatever you want to get rid of"

newLines = []
for line in lines:
    newLines.append(' '.join([word for word in line.split() if word != 
    excludedWord]))

f = open("file.txt", 'w')
for line in lines:
f.write("{}\n".format(line))
f.close()
```

This might be of some use!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Muhammad Anas actually its not a word i want to exclude i want to remove the whole line before a specific word

Answer (score 0):

```py
# open two files: one for reading, one for writing
with open('file.txt', 'rt') as in_, open('out.txt', 'wt') as out:
    # if we're considering two lines, we have to store the other one
    old_line = None
    for line in in_:  # iterating over a text file gives lines
        if old_line is not None and "Ctrl+S" not in line:
            # we can write the previous line each iteration
            out.write(old_line)
        old_line = line
    if old_line is not None:
        # but we have to make sure to write the last one,
        # since it's never the previous line
        out.write(old_line)
```

This approach doesn't store the whole file in memory, so it works for larger files – so long as a *line* isn't too long, that is!

Comment: @PMoto500 Try running `for line in open("file.txt"): print(repr(line))` and show the _exact_ output for the Ctrl+S line.

Comment: Probably better to do `'Ctrl+S' not in line`

Comment: @BeRT2me Given the edited question, that seems a good suggestion.