# How to delete a line before specific word with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, line, file-handling

so I have text file `file.txt` e.g

```
something1
something2
something3
line to be removed
2022-07-21 >>  Ctrl+S
something4
something5
something6
something7
line to be removed
2022-07-21 >>  Ctrl+S
```

now how do I make it delete **one** line **before** the word `Ctrl+S` in the whole file.

So that the outputfile will be

```
something1
something2
something3
2022-07-21 >>  Ctrl+S
something4
something5
something6
something7
2022-07-21 >>  Ctrl+S
```

Thank you

Comment: How big is the file? (aka, do you need an efficient solution, or just one that works)

Comment: One way is to read the file into a list of strings one line at a time and if the "Ctrl+S" line is detected, then remove the previous line in the list. Try implementing that and see if it works. You can write the output to an output file at the end or as you go in append mode.

Comment: @BeRT2me The file is big but not that big . and i need a solution just so it works

Comment: @Bill yes thats what I want . But how do  I do it

Comment: @PMoto500 What have you tried so far? Looking at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) may be a good place to start, but we don't really know what's keeping you from being able to do it yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as desired;

```
keyword = 'Ctrl+S'
new_content = []

with open('textfile.txt', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    prev_index = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(content):
        if keyword in line:
            new_content += content[prev_index:i - 1]
            prev_index = i
    new_content += content[prev_index:]
with open('textfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("".join(new_content))
```

Comment: `open(mode='w')` already truncates the file.

Comment: `f.read().split('\n')` is the same as `f.readlines()`, just worse in this situation because yours removes `\n` so they have to be added again later.

Comment: That's very true! Nice to learn some new things myself:)

Comment: @AndersHaarbergEriksen thank you sir this worked for me . And I have been trying since yesterday to do it my self I tried a lot before even coming to stack over flow for help . but i just couldn't figure it out . And if I try to do it myself and it doesn't work I just almost immediately remove that code

Comment: No worries! That's great to hear:D

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a single open statement. Hope it helps you.

```
with open("textfile.txt", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for pos, line in enumerate(lines):
        if len(lines)-1 !=pos:
            if "Ctrl+S" in lines[pos+1]:
                continue
        f.write(line)
    f.truncate()
```

Comment: Sir this answer is also correct thank you for your kindness and help

Answer (score 0):

You might do smth of the kind:

```
with open("python_cisco\programs\list.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines() # number of bits not to overload your system
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        try:
            if "Ctrl+S" in lines[i]:
                lines.remove(lines[i - 1])
        except:
            pass

with open("python_cisco\programs\list2.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in lines:
    f.write(i)
```

This will basically rewrite the list without unnecessary lines to a different file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).